Can I use Mica material for a kotlin multiplatform app？
I am using kmp to build my app which can run on Windows and other platforms. I found that kmp could implement Aero Snap. So is there any way that I could use the Mica material in my app just like a native Windows app?
I heard that the Java Native Interface could access Windows API, could it help?
